# Show that a preorder can be extended to a weak order

Tags: order-theory

A preorder is defined as a binary relation on a finite set that is reflexive and transitive. And a weak order is defined as  a binary relation that is complete and transitive. I am wondering how to show that a preorder can be extended to a weak order?

Comment: Can you use the Axiom of Choice or equivalent statements? Or perhaps are you assuming that the set is finite?

Comment: Yes, I just updated.